# Customizing the login flow for Azure AD B2C - using it without user/pass

Tags: android, ios, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've been looking at options for authentication for a REST web api (.NET Core, but that's besides the point).

In particular I'm looking at Azure AD B2C.

I have two use cases:

1) An app. In the app I don't want the user to use a user/pass at all (nor social identities). When the user first opens the app he'll enter his phone number, I'll send that to a service that exists in my country, it will prompt his phone to log him in and return to me his "social security number" equivalent. This service can be trusted to identify this user.

When the user next opens the app I just want him to remain logged in - either that or he should only have to use biometrics (touchId or faceId). How would I go about implementing this typically? And is it even possible in Azure AD B2C?

2) A web app that will use the same "service" - i.e. you enter the phone number, the service is called and it will tell me if the user authenticated successfully or not. I don't want to use user/pass here either. The difference between this and the app is that in this we'd use the service every time, the user wouldn't be logged in for extended periods of time.

3) A web client using user/pass.. I think this would work using Azure AD B2C using the "Resource Owner Password Credential" flow (to avoid redirects - I don't understand why I would use either implicit flow/authorization code when both the client and the service are written by me. The redirect would just seem silly in a SPA where the AS is mine and the client is mine).

4) Optional: A service-to-service application. This could be done simply using the client credentials flow in Azure AD (not sure if B2C has that? ) - i.e. the app just sends its id along with a secret (and optionally signs the request with it's client certificate). I guess my question here is if anyone knows if this can be done with Azure AD B2C - I know it can with Azure AD.

Any assistance would be appreciated! Whether it's pointing to resources or something else, but I've done a lot of reading in the Microsoft docs.

Comment: B2C does not currently support the client credentials flow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#daemonsserver-side-applications

Comment: It sounds like you don't need AzureAD B2C. The phone number service you talk about is the authenticating party. You may need to build your own OAuth service that wraps that.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Right, I'd prefer to use an existing solution if possible. But if I were to roll one myself, are there any resources you can point me to? Also, what do you think about using ROPC for user/pass? In order to avoid redirects from a single page application.

Comment: You could use ROPC if you don’t need SSO and the user trusts you with the password.  The problem I see is that you are trying to use AzureAD but it isn’t actually the authenticating party. I understand that you don’t want to do this, but it would be simpler if you just had the user set up a username/password in Azure AD after verifying the first time using their phone number.  You may also need to consider the pending requirement that you support sign in with Apple